# invalid_json in curl using variable in POST

Tags: json, bash, variables, curl

Can someone plz tell me, when I launch just curl with POST some json data it works, but when I'm trying to add variable in json and cycle `for`, bash returns `invalid_json`.

I've read that bash variables are untyped so why I got this error?

```
#!/bin/bash

    for var in 14456 14455 
    do
    curl -X POST -d '{"api_token": "test_api", "id": $var}' 'https://api_test.com/'
    done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need [double quotes](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) to do variable interpolation in bash:

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"api_token\": \"test_api\", \"id\": $var}" 'https://api_test.com/'
```